# Build tools structure - NPM, Grunt with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, npm, gruntjs

I want to integrate some build tools like `NPM` and `Grunt` whilst i'm working on my `Wordpress` theme. Eg...I'll write some `Sass` to compile it down to an `.css` file.

Where do the build files like grunt file and node_modules folder live within the wordpress theme?

There's documents on how to do it but not many documents on how it is structured.

How do you structure build tools to work with a wordpress theme?

Answer (score 0):

I usually compile my own version of css from scratch when doing a client website - using built in tools suggested by either bootstrap, bulma or uxkit. For bulma you have a nice introduction on how to compile their framework

https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/

In my workflow - I don't know if that would be optimal for everyone - I put wordpress files on the same level as node_modules folder but compile straight to wordpress theme folder, so my build command is as follows:

```
"css-build": "node-sass --omit-source-map-url src/scss/app.scss ../wp-content/themes/labaza/app.css",
```

So in this case when you take your files from local machine to server you just overwrite theme folder, and need to make sure that you're not uploading any node_modules.

Hope that helps - but as I wrote it's only my idea based on how I like to work.

Comment: So your package.json, node modules folder, gruntfile, git ignore are in the root of your theme? Then you push the whole folder to Github (minus the node_modules) folder?

Comment: No no - not in the root of my theme - in the root of my local project catalogue. When I push to git I have everything in gitignore except for wp-content